# Comprendiendo las secuencias de escape en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo problemas para comprender la utilidad de las secuencias de escape.

Para introducir en el interior de una cadena de caracteres algunos caracteres especiales imposibles de representar mediante texto, utilizamos lo que comúnmente se denominan secuencias de escape.

fuente:https://doc.velneo.es/secuencias-de-escape-en-cadenas-de-caracteres.html

Quiero algunos ejemplos para ver la utilidad de los mismos en **javascript** o mas información acerca de este tema.

Answer (score 0):

La secuencia de escape es (de forma simple) una herramienta de apoyo para representar aquellos caracteres que en ocasiones no podemos introducir directamente con el teclado, ya sea por restricciones físicas o lógicas. Ejemplo un emoji o salto de línea:

```
let emoji = '\u{1F60D}';
let saltoLinea = '¡Hola\nmundo!';
let textoConComilla = 'Comilla simple (\'), comilla doble (").';
```

[image: Ejemplo de emoji en js]

El lenguaje toma al reconocer una secuencia de escape, traduce lo que el código conlleva, logrando ser de utilidad tanto para el programador como para el usuario.

Te recomiendo la lectura siguiente: [Strings - javascript.info](http://javascript.info/string).